# how to select and show data comment by id post in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

master peace of codeigniter. im new user for this framework. 
i have problem to show comment data by id_diskusi in the single post of diskusi. i try to show data using 'where' in the lybrary code but its still not show the data. i hope the people at there can help me & solved this problem.

i use library to get data from database

```
public function setuju(){
    $data=$this->CI->db->query("SELECT komentar.id AS id,
     komentar.diskusi_id AS id_diskusi,
     komentar.pilih AS pilih,
     komentar.nama AS nama,
     komentar.email AS email,
     komentar.pesan AS pesan,
     komentar.tanggal AS tanggal,
     diskusi.diskusi_id as nomor_diskusi
     FROM diskusi, komentar
     WHERE diskusi.diskusi_status='publish' AND komentar.pilih='1' AND komentar.diskusi_id=diskusi.diskusi_id  ORDER BY komentar.id DESC
     ");
    return $data->result_array();
}
```

i use this code to filter data who data on komentar will be show by id of diskusi.

```
komentar.diskusi_id=diskusi.diskusi_id
```

but still not work

and its my controller

```
$data['setuju']=$this->diskusi->setuju();
```

code in the view

```
<div id="netral" class="tab-pane">
                <?php
                foreach ($netral AS $value) {
                  echo "<div class='box box-body no-border'>
                  <div class='row'>
                      <div class='col-md-2'>
                        <div class='box-profile'>"; ?>
                          <img alt='user image' style='margin-top:10px' class='profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle' src='<?php echo img_user_url('user.png'); ?>'>
                          <?php echo"
                          <h3><center>$value[nama]</center</h3>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class='col-md-10'>
                          <div class='callout callout-danger lead'><span class='pull-right'>".format_tanggal($value['tanggal'])."</span><br>
                           <p>$value[pesan]</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>";
                }?>
              </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
<div class="box box-danger">
              <div class="box-header with-border">
              <div class="user-block">
                <h3 class="no-margin">Tinggalkan Komentar</h3>
              </div><!-- /.user-block -->
              <div class="box-tools">
                <button data-widget="collapse" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
              </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
            </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                      <form method='POST' id='komentar' action='<?php echo baseURL('form_visitors/komentar'); ?>' autocomplete='off' method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="hidden" name="diskusi_id" value="<?php echo "$diskusi[id]";?>">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Nama" data-original-title="Masukkan Nama" required='required' name="nama" id="inputName" class="form-control">                          
                      <input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='url' value='<?php echo current_url() ?>' />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="email" name="email" data-original-title="Masukkan Email" placeholder="Email" required='required' id="inputEmail" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="pilih" value="1"> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up margin-r-5 text-green"> <b>Setuju</b></i>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" name="pilih" value="2"> <i class="fa fa-square margin-r-5 text-yellow"> <b>Netral</b></i>  
                        </label>
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" name="pilih" value="3"> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down margin-r-5 text-red"> <b>Tidak Setuju</b></i>
                         </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputExperience">Komentar</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <textarea placeholder="Komentar" name="pesan" id="inputExperience" required='required' class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='form-group'>
                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputExperience"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div id='recaptcha1'></div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                      <div class="cssload" style="display: none; width: 100px">
                      <div class="cssload-tube-tunnel"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                </div>
              </div>
```

how can i show comment data according with single post of diskusi who have comment. Thank you very much in advance!  sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are fetching the data from two different tables but you have not used 'JOIN'.
you can try the following query string :

```
    public function setuju(){
    $data=$this->CI->db->query("SELECT komentar.id AS id,
     komentar.diskusi_id AS id_diskusi,
     komentar.pilih AS pilih,
     komentar.nama AS nama,
     komentar.email AS email,
     komentar.pesan AS pesan,
     komentar.tanggal AS tanggal,
     diskusi.diskusi_id as nomor_diskusi
     FROM komentar, diskusi
     JOIN diskusi
     ON diskusi.diskusi_id=komentar.diskusi_id
     WHERE diskusi.diskusi_status='publish' AND komentar.pilih='1' ORDER BY komentar.id DESC
         ");
        return $data->result_array();

}
```

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'diskusi'

SELECT komentar.id AS id, komentar.diskusi_id AS id_diskusi, komentar.pilih AS pilih, komentar.nama AS nama, komentar.email AS email, komentar.pesan AS pesan, komentar.tanggal AS tanggal, diskusi.diskusi_id as nomor_diskusi FROM komentar, diskusi JOIN diskusi ON diskusi.diskusi_id=komentar.diskusi_id WHERE diskusi.diskusi_status='publish' AND komentar.pilih='1' ORDER BY komentar.id DESC

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/ci/ci-rilisitas/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691